# Using azure storage client library with xamarin

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I would like to use Azure Storage directly from my cross platform Xamarin app.

The way I would do it if I were only supporting Windows 8 or Windows Phone 8 would be to use the Storage Client Library. I was wondering whether that same library could be used from Xamarin but I have found no examples so far. I am not interested in using some partly maintained third party library, so the only other alternative would be to use the REST interface.

Does anybody know if the library is supported in Xamarin?

Comment: Are you referring to this component? http://components.xamarin.com/view/azure-mobile-services

Comment: No I am referring to this one: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-storage-net

Answer (score 1):

I've just built a simple test Xamarin.Forms app that uses the [Azure Storage](http://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage) NuGet

[Teal: Azure Storage demo](https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-samples/tree/master/Azure/Teal)

It has Blob, Table, and Queue examples. The solution includes a simple console application that can be used to generate Sas (Shared Access Signatures) that you paste into the source code to test with. In a "real" app you'd retrieve these from a server component (to avoid hardcoding values in your app) -- the sample does not address this server-code requirement.

The code then becomes as simple as

```
// Return a reference to the container using the SAS URI.
CloudBlobContainer container = new CloudBlobContainer(new Uri(sas));
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString();
try
{
    //Write operation: write a new blob to the container. 
    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("xamarinblob_" + date + ".txt");

    string blobContent = textEntry.Text; //"This blob was created with a shared access signature granting write permissions to the container. ";
    MemoryStream msWrite = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(blobContent));
    msWrite.Position = 0;
    using (msWrite)
    {
        await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(msWrite);
    }
}
// Blob has now been uploaded
```

p.s. don't forget to replace the `FROM_PORTAL` placeholders in the code with *your* auth info from the Azure portal...

Answer (score 0):

I see no reasons why [this](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-storage-net) would not work on Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Android.
Usually, if it is working on Windows Phone 8, it'll work on other mobile platforms too. The other way round is a different story. WP8 often is lacking namespaces available on Android and iOS.

Why not just give it a try? Add the project to your iOS solution, create an iOS Test Runner project and see how far you can get.

If you encounter issues, you can sill fall back to a workaround: [use Xamarin's component for Azure](http://components.xamarin.com/view/azure-mobile-services) for iOS and Android and the other one for WP8.

You can also create an interface with the methods you need and abstract Azure access.

Comment: *Why not just give it a try?* Just did. "Could not link assemblies. Reason: Argument is out of range. (MT2001)